# Find files with {{ ds }} in it

Tags: python, airflow

In Airflow is,
`date = '{{  ds_nodash }}'`
is date variable here a string?
I am trying to filter for filenames based on this date variable and it's not returning anything
I am trying to do a subset of a list of files -
`download_files = [x for x in files if date in x]` this doesn't work
but
`download_files = [x for x in files if '20201108' in x]` this works

Comment: Could you provide the whole code sample? Which operator are you using?

Comment: @PhilippJohannis - I believe I was using the date outside the operator

Comment: You can't access ´{{  ds_nodash }}´ outside an operator, it's a template and gets rendered when the DAG Run gets executed.